# SQL date format from float (without a '1')

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been given some data where there is a 'float' column that contains a date with a 1 in the front of it. I.e the value 1171030 represents 30th October 2017.

I am stuck in attempting to convert it to a normal date, when attempting to remove the one a dot appears (i.e. .171030).

Would really appreciate some guidance.

Many thanks

Comment: How does the date field appear for days/months less than 10? (e.g. Jan 1, 2017)

Comment: It's relative to 1900.

Comment: I'm not following. What does relative to 1900 mean? I was wondering if Jan 1, 2017 is 11711 or 1170101.

Comment: @user01CU812 Sorry, I wasn't referring to your question.

Comment: 1171205 for 5th December 2017.

Comment: Just store dates as dates...

Answer (score 1):

Yuck!  Let's try `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts((val - 100000) / 10000, floor(val / 100) % 100, val % 100)
```

Or, here is another approach:

```
select convert(date, right(convert(varchar(255), cast(val as int)), 6))
```

SQL Server is actually pretty flexible in the date formats it understands.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help. Unfortunately I get errors when I try both.
The first one: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."The data types float and int are incompatible in the modulo operator."
The second one "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Just fyi: The second option will have the potential snag in two digit year cutoff: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-two-digit-year-cutoff-server-configuration-option

Comment: @chelsjo . . . You describe the column as a *float*.  There are no string operations in the first query.  I think your data is different from what you have described.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this was probably produced by a non-Y2K compliant method such as JavaScript `getYear()` which simply returns current year minus 1900. It's not clear to me whether this data is coming from a flat file or it is already imported into a database table.

If you treat this value as a character string:

```
case length(val)
    when 7 then cast('20' + right(val, 6) as date)
    when 6 then cast('19' + val as date)
end
```

If you truly have a float (or int) value:

```
cast(cast(cast(19000000 + @val as int) as char(8)) as date)
```

In this case you'll need to convert through a character value rather than going straight to date. Be careful with string conversions from float to char. If you prefer shorter then you may be able to get away with this one:

```
cast(str(19000000 + @val, 8) as date);
```

You might get errors by assuming a length of 8 but that's probably a good way to catch and prevent problems.

Comment: Could he just add 19,000,000 to val and then cast it to a date?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing except I don't know which assumptions I can make about datatype. And many people tend to shy away from "magical" methods like that.

Comment: I think putting a non-standard date value in a 'float' column throws best practice out the window anyway. :)